# Broadcasting Raspberry Pi Camera Over Hotel Wireless Internet

Tags: raspbian, wireless, camera, streaming-video, vpn

I am interested in configuring my Raspberry Pi to be able to stream video from the standard Raspberry Pi camera to a website.  However, I am on travel with my Raspberry Pi and will be limited at times by hotel wireless (more specifically, port forwarding being limited).  Are there methods that I can implement to stream video over hotel wireless in such a scenario?  I have had video stream to a local website using [elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface] but due to port restrictions, I cannot have it available to the general public.

I was considering the possibility of having a VPN connection to my private network at home but am not sure if this is possible (or how I would get a Raspberry Pi to VPN to a Windows network, let alone stream the video over it).

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Welcome -- but this is not really a pi-specific question since the hardware is irrelevant (if the computer you wanted to stream from had an Acme motherboard, would you bother asking this on a forum for owners of Acme equipment?).  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) if you have not yet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want the video to be visible from the Internet and not just within the hotel, correct?

Assuming you can redirect ports internally on your home network, you could simply create a tunnel from the RPi to your home server and use port redirection with ssh (assuming you can install ssh on your home server). I've done something similar using a virtual server hosted on Amazon's AWS cloud. Performance might be pretty poor though since traffic will have to travel in and out of your home connection, then back through the tunnel over sometimes-spotty hotel wireless. It will certainly vary by hotel.

Does it need to be real-time live video? It might be better to record, then transfer the recording to your home or Internet-hosted server.